# Codeigniter form validation $_POST nested fields

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I need to set form validation rules in codeigniter from an AJAX call
The call generates a $_POST array where i nest data from different forms (1:N) and then I set validation rules in this way:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules($field, $label , $rules);
```

and the $_POST array will be similar at this:

```
field1: value1
field2: value2
field3: value3
field4: value4
field5: value5
field6: value6      
id: 86
operation: "add"
```

clearly, some forms may have colliding names, and this solution is not reliable.

For example

```
field1:value1
field1:value2
```

names are given dinamically, so i can't afford to change them.

I choose to nest values in $_POST array:

```
form: 
    form1: 
           field1: value1
           field2: value2
    form2: 
           field1: value3
           field2: value4
    form3: 
           field1: value5
           field2: value6
id: 86
operation: "add"
```

but now form_validation is broken.

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form[form1['.fieldN .']', $label   , $rules);
```

does not work as expected: i cannot validate. Looking into Form_validation.php library, set_rules first paramer is a string, and its value can be an array, but i can't go deeper with nesting e.g. array of array.
There is a way to do this?Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass array as a field name like this

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('options[]', 'Options', 'required');
```

refer a [details documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields) for using array in Codeigniter's validation class.

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('form[form_name]', 'try' , 'required'); works, but i need to add another nesting level, and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yes. I reverted to 2 level and it runs fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into this link for [reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) how to set rules using a single array for all the fields.

You can set rules for different forms in same array in a nested array like this.

```
$config['login_form'] = array (
                        array 
                        (
                            'key' => 'email', 
                            'value' => 'Email',
                            'rule' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
                        ),
                        array
                        (
                            'key' => 'passwd', 
                            'value' => 'Password',
                            'rule' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|xss_clean'
                        )
                      );
 $config['login_form_error_code_1'] = 'The email or password you entered is incorrect';                       

 $config['add_user_form'] = array(
                            array(
                                    'key' => 'user_email',
                                    'value' => ' User Email',
                                    'rule' => 'trim|required|valid_email|callback_duplicate_user_email_check|xss_clean'
                                    ),
                            array(
                                    'key' => 'user_name',
                                    'value' => 'User Name',
                                    'rule' => 'trim|required|xss_clean'
                                     ),
                            array(
                                    'key' => 'user_phone',
                                    'value'=> 'Mobile',
                                    'rule' => 'trim|required|integer|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|xss_clean'
                                    ),
                            array
                            (
                                    'key' => 'user_password',
                                    'value' => 'Password',
                                    'rule' => 'trim|required|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|xss_clean'
                            )


    );
```

Now all your rules for different forms in same array $config.

Comment: Already seen. As I understand it just say that i can assign same ruleset to a fixed fieldset (e.g. checkboxes). I've dynamic fields name with dynamic rules, my problem is to bind $_POST[form[formname[fieldname]]] to the correct set_rules(fieldname, label, rules)

Comment: do u want to put all the rules in one array for different forms

Comment: $this->form_validation->set_rules('form[form_name]', 'try'   , 'required');  works, but i need to add another nesting level, and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: sorry, was a nesting levels issue and not a populating one ;)

Comment: i just reverted to two nesting levels from three and it works. The form_validation library seems to accept at most 2.

Comment: if my code helps in any way support it with a vote. Thanks for the question to explore some concepts.